# Input ReactJS with function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I work on a reactJS code coded by a freelance (i'm new in reactJS), and I need to make the inputs functional.

But when I look at the tutorials and solutions on the internet, you have to use controlled components, they are always built with a class and not a function.

However all the components present in the project are built with functions.

Is it possible to make the inputs functional anyway? In order to have the output in a console.log see keep the data to use it on other pages?

See my Input component :

```
import React from 'react'
// Import styles
import './style.scss'

const BaseTextInput = ({
  className = '',
  id = '',
  name = '',
  size = 'normal',
  type = 'text',
  value = '',
  placeholder = '',
  disabled = false,
  top = false,
  onChange,
  children,
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (
    <form>
    <div
      className={`text-input text-input__size-${size} ${top ? 'text-input__top' : ''} ${className}`}
      {...rest}
    >
      {children && <label>{children}</label>}
      <input
        className="text-input__input"
        id={id}
        name={name}
        type={type}
        value={value}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        disabled={disabled}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </div>
    </form>
  )
}

export default BaseTextInput
```

Thank you, I hope I explained my problem clearly

EDIT 26/02/201 10h23:

Thank you for all, I understand how I can do it !!

Comment: "Is it possible to make the inputs functional anyway?" Yes, absolutely it is. It appears you've a functional component input, though I doubt you want a `form` element wrapping it all. What is the issue?

Comment: By the way, controlled vs uncontrolled inputs have nothing at all to do with being a class-based or functional component. "all the components present in the project are built with functions" Good news, class-based components are still compatible and valid React, so you can use them still if that is what you are more familiar with.

Comment: Functional components can be controlled component. For this you have to use `useState()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use your sample component to make a CodeSandbox for you, but I'm not sure if this is what you want.

[image: Edit TextField selectionStart]

```
import InputComponent from "./inputComponent";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [inputData, setInputData] = useState("");
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setInputData(value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      Your input component
      <InputComponent onChange={handleChange} value={inputData} />
      <br />
      Input value: <b>{inputData}</b>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hope to help you !

Answer (score 0):

I think onChange method of parent component is passed as a prop to this functional component , if you want you could make your onChange method for this component